# Does Prisma (typescript) generate a schema without generated values?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm using Prisma to generate my database schema, which includes the auto generated default value of ID:

```
model User {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    age Int
}
```

However, whenever I import the user schema that is generated like :

```
import { User } from "@prisma/client";
```

It always has id in the object shape - however, this cannot be used when I am for example, running a create function, as it always complains that id is missing (the create shape should be.

```
{
"name": "john",
"age": 13
}
```

Is there anything Prisma generates that doesn't include auto generated values? I could create my own seperate DTO class/interface, however that would mean there isn't a single point of truth for the schema, which i'm not a huge fan of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `prisma generate` with a schema of `User` like the one in the questions, you can run

```js
prisma.user.create({ data: { name: "john", age: 13 } });
```

without any issues.

You can check `UserCreateInput`:

```js
  export type UserCreateInput = {
    name: string
    age: number
  }
```

Just as a side note: You may want to think, if you really want to tie your API definition (DTO, etc.) to the database structure. Although that seems nice on first sight, it introduces strong coupling that might be hindering future enhancements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate a bit more on the seperation of concerns surrounding the DTO? To my assesment, having a singular point of truth means that if things change, it only needs to be changed in the single place - could you elaborate on your thoughs, and my it might seem nice at first but in reality isnt?

Comment: That doesn't really fit into a comment here. An interface/API should abstract from the underlying implementation. That allows to change the implementation without changing the interface. If you basically use your database schema as API, you have a tight coupling without any abstraction. It gives you speed in initial development, but reduces flexibility later on.